# What is the gradient tool XML structure for Inkskape extension programing.?

Tags: inkscape, xml

I want to create a custom gradient tool extension. what is the XML structure for the gradient tool? The tool I want to make would fill objects with N-vectors per (unit of measurement) to make vector-based cross-hatching efficient.

I’m looking at [this](https://inkscape.org/develop/extensions).

Further more, how would I get the XML structures for all of the tool tips available?

Comment: like this one: https://github.com/evil-mad/EggBot/blob/master/inkscape_driver/eggbot_hatch.py ? There are no gradients involved in vector based cross-hatches. I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: yeah not yet, i haven't made the thing yet. Im going to use the gradient tool tip, and functionally control to create vectors in stead of raster gradients. it should make shading much more efficient to cut using a laser.  There are also some interesting carving-without-burning thing one can do with a laser and many closely parallel lines.  The tool im going to make with make drawing those lines much faster.  Does theat eggbot code create an inkscape widget?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what Inkscape python extensions are able to do. Unless you program a C++ extension, that needs to be present at build time, or create a separate program with its own GUI in Python, and start that from an Inkscape extension, there's no way to 'create a tool' with an Inkscape extension. Check out other extensions - none of them does this.

Comment: However, you could ask the users to apply a gradient with the gradient tool, and then pick apart the gradient with the extension and turn it into hatches.

Comment: Im not asking how to code it, im asking what the name of the tool tip is, as an xml parameter.

Comment: You don't by any chance mean this: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/INX_Parameters#gui-description

Comment: Or what is a tool tip to you? For me, it's a text that shows up when you hover with the mouse over something in the GUI.

Comment: If you mean you want to use the gradient tool's cursor on the canvas, then: There is no way to do that with Python extensions currently (unless you write your own user interface with Tkinter, for example).

Comment: Thanks @Moini, thats what i wanted to know.